# How to Install Matplotlib for Python 3.9 in Windows?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I cannot seem to figure out how to install Matplotlib for Python 3.9 on Windows. These are the commands I have entered into Command Prompt and none of them have worked.

```
$ python -m pip install --user matplotlib

$ python3 -m pip install --user matplotlib

python3 -m pip install matplotlib --pre --user

py -m pip install -U matplotlib --user
```

The first two give this error message:

```
'$' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

The second gives this error message:

```
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.
```

The third seemed to have downloaded everything, but when I try to run Matplotlib in Python, it gives me this error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\costr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\temporary.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

Here is the code I am trying to run:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

squares=[1, 4, 9, 16, 25]

fig, ax=plt.subplots()
ax.plot(squares)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry if this isn't much help but shouldn't
`pip install matplotlib`
or
`python -m pip install --user matplotlib`(fist command without the $)
work?

You can also use `pip freeze` to check if the module is installed or not.